# How do I Call highlightRow of ListView.renderRow()?

Tags: listview, react-native

I can't seem to figure out how to use the `highlightRow` attribute ListView's renderRow.

The [ListView.renderRow Documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow) states...

> **(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable**
>
> Takes a data entry from the data source and its ids and should return a renderable component to be rendered as the row. By default the data is exactly what was put into the data source, but it's also possible to provide custom extractors. ListView can be notified when a row is being highlighted by calling highlightRow function. The separators above and below will be hidden when a row is highlighted. The highlighted state of a row can be reset by calling highlightRow(null).

I'd like to call attention to the line...

> ListView can be notified when a row is being highlighted by calling highlightRow function.

when I `console.log(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightedRow)`, I can see that the highlightedRow is a function with the following signature...

```
function(sectionID,rowID){
  this.setState({highlightedRow:{sectionID:sectionID,rowID:rowID}});
}
```

which is called from [here in the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js#L379) (see `this.onRowHighlighted`)...

```
<StaticRenderer
  key={'r_' + comboID}
  shouldUpdate={!!shouldUpdateRow}
  render={this.props.renderRow.bind(
    null,
    dataSource.getRowData(sectionIdx, rowIdx),
    sectionID,
    rowID,
    this.onRowHighlighted
  )}
/>;
```

Can anyone provide an example how to use highlightRow properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating `highlightedRow` state property in ListView code, i've seen that it's only used to calculate `adjacentRowHighlighted` parameter that is passed to `renderSeparator` method.

> **(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted) => renderable**
>
> If provided, a renderable component to be rendered as the separator
>   below each row but not the last row if there is a section header
>   below. Take a sectionID and rowID of the row above and whether its
>   adjacent row is highlighted.

So, i believe the only use case for `highlightRow` would be rendering a different separator for highlighted rows. Here is a simple example that changes separator background colour based on `adjacentRowHighlighted` argument.

```
<ListView
  renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => highlightRow(sectionID, rowID)
        >
          {row content here}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }}
  renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted) => {
    return (
      <View
        key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`}
        style={{
          height: 1,
          backgroundColor: adjacentRowHighlighted ? 'blue' : 'red',
        }} 
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

Comment: @halib, I definitely think you're on the right track, but I wasn't able to get your example working. I'm digging in, but did you by chance happen to test this yourself to see if it actually worked?

Comment: BTW, I put a copy up on rnplay of where I am right now. It would be awesome if you'd fork it and help me get it working https://rnplay.org/apps/FW4-Aw

Comment: @ChrisGeirman, the problem is with separator width. it can't be calculated as row's and listview's width are not defined. Adding something like width: 200; style for ListView would fix it: https://rnplay.org/apps/Bs9wZQ

Comment: well done @halilb *applause* thank you for your help. Can you think of a way to use this to change the background color of the highlighted row?

Comment: i don't think it's possible with current ListView implementation. I guess you either should change the ListView code to pass adjacentRowHighlighted parameter to the render method, or you should implement it in own component by yourself.